# Subscribing to Firebase realtime database ChildChange event fires event with children not from the subscribed path

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working with firebase realtime database in Unity and I'm making a chat/inbox system.
The problem/unoptimized thing is that I've subscribed my ChildChanged like this:

```
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("inbox/" + myUserID).ChildChanged += OnListenerGotChangedInboxItem;
```

so its supposed to return children that are changed from the path:
"inbox/" + myUserID

and I'm saving data like this for OnMessagePost using UpdateChildrenAsync:

```
Dictionary<string, object> dictToSend = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        // Set in messages
        dictToSend["/messages/" + myUserID + "/" + otherUser + "/" + key] = entryValues;
        dictToSend["/messages/" + otherUser + "/" + myUserID + "/" + key] = entryValues;

        // Set in inbox
        // Yours
        dictToSend["/inbox/" + myUserID + "/" + otherUser] = userInboxItem.ToDict();

        // Theirs
        dictToSend["/inbox/" + otherUser + "/" + myUserID + "/username"] = UserManager.instance.username;
        dictToSend["/inbox/" + otherUser + "/" + myUserID + "/user_id"] = UserManager.instance.userId;
        dictToSend["/inbox/" + otherUser + "/" + myUserID + "/unread"] = true;
        dictToSend["/inbox/" + otherUser + "/" + myUserID + "/text"] = messagePreviewText;
        dictToSend["/inbox/" + otherUser + "/" + myUserID + "/last_sent_date"] = message.time_sent;

        // Increase their unread count by one
        dictToSend["/unread/" + otherUser + "/" + myUserID] = "true";

        UserManager.instance.rootRef.UpdateChildrenAsync(dictToSend).ContinueWith(task => ...
```

And the OnChildChanged fires for the path "inbox/myUserID" and also fires for "inbox/otherUser" as well, even tho I'm only subscribed to ChildChanged for "inbox/myUserID"

If you have any better way for my to track incoming messages, Im all ears, but really im just curious why its triggering the event on a path im not subscribed to, but i suspect it has something to do with saving multiple children together on one UpdateChildrenAsync call.

As this is my first ever post on here I appreciate any help(:

Comment: I suggest narrowing this down to a [complete, minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that anyone can copy and run in isolation and reproduce the issue.  If these snippets of code are running along with other code, we don't know how that other code might be affecting the way this works.  In particular, you should hard code all the values, because we can't see what you're using for variables here.

Comment: I've never seen the Firebase client fire `childChanged` events for a node that you're not subscribed to, so you might want to double/triple check that you're really not subscribing to the other inbox too.

Comment: What you're describing really shouldn't happen. If you can reproduce it in the Unity test app ( https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/tree/master/database/testapp ), you should file a bug on the related issue tracker ( https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues ). Otherwise, definitely double check your usages of `OnListenerGotChangedInboxItem;` as Puf mentioned and maybe try chaining .GetReference calls: `database.GetReference("inbox").GetReference(myUserID)` (if chaining helps, please file an issue in the tracker I linked above as well).

Comment: It's also never too early to add security rules. Once you work this out, I would suggest making sure that you remove "read" access to other users inboxes. See this on security rules: https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#realtime-database